# HTML5 sourcebuffer stalls in firefox

Tags: firefox, html5-video

I'm learning the use of the hml5 `<video>` tag. I'm making a simple video server with node.js, socket.io, HTML5 and some signaling. This is the essential chunk on the server:

```
        ffmpeg()
            .input('video.mp4')
            ...
            .pipe()
            .on('data', function(data) {
                socket.emit('data', data );
            });
```

In the client, I have:

```
    const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    videoElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    socket.on('connect', () => {socket.emit('offer', 'start');});
    mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", (event) => {
        const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs=vp8');
        socket.on('data', (data) => {
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data); // <----- HERE!!!
        });
    });
```

In Chromium, this works fine. But in Firefox, it seems like the `appendBuffer()` is not sending the data to the **mediaSource** (debugging, I find the sourceBuffer tends to grow, just add a `console.log(sourceBuffer.buffered);`: it tends to grow).

Why is the sourceBuffer in Firefox not transferring the data to the mediaSource?

If you want to test it, find the full application [here](https://gist.github.com/rodolfoap/cf198d9ea5d793b71ee5c021712e06d1). Yes, I'm sure that Firefox can reproduce the video. Yes, I have an updated Firefox.